# accessing vpc rds instance from vpc windows ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

We are trying to move from the classic to vpc instances on Amazon.
We already have some rds databases on amazon that are accessible from linux vpc instances.
I have created an oracle vpc and as I try to access it from my windows vcp image, it times out.
- the same oracle db with the same host and credentials is accessible from my desktop.
- it is also accessible from a linux vpc instance - can be telnet-ed to
- I cannot access the oracle instance from my amazon windows vcp
- I cannot telnet to it from my vpc windows instance
- I've used the same security group as the other dbs. That is all traffic inbound and outbound plus another security group with tcp/udp ports open to my desktop ip.

Any ideas why I cannot connect to my amazon oracle database from an amazon ec2 vpc instance?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. I needed to add that security group also to the ec2 instance.
Adding the security group just to the vpc and the rds was not enough.